# Handling multiple number type inputs

Tags: reactjs

I have several number type inputs in one page view. If I enter a number in one input, the value of all inputs changes. I only have one value in state, to which I assign the variable from input. How to control only the input that the target is on?

Parent:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    starships: [],
    value: 0,
    quantity: 0,
  };

  handleInputChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value,
    });
  };


  render() {
    const { starships, value, quantity } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <>
        <Header quantity={quantity} />
        <StarshipsList
          starships={starships}
          value={value}
          quantity={quantity}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          onClick={this.handleAddBtn}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Child's child:

```
function Starship(props) {
  return (
    <tbody>
      {props.starships.map(({ url, name, manufacturer, cost_in_credits }) => (
        <tr key={url}>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{manufacturer}</td>
          <td>{cost_in_credits}</td>
          <td>
            <input
              onChange={props.onChange}
              value={props.value}
              className="input"
              type="number"
              min="0"
            />
            <button onClick={props.onClick} className="add-btn">
              Add
            </button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  );
}
```

Comment: do you want to have a single value for all inputs or do you want an individual one for each?

Comment: each starship will have its own state then (with a value and onChange handler). Just extract that input into a separate stateful component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to create a component (`TrComponent`) to render the `tr` tag and child.
- In `TrComponent`, you create a state call `value` and handle change to update this state
- To handle `onClick` in `TrComponent`, you can update like: `onClick={() => props.onClick(values_you_want)}`

Answer (score 0):

First of all change `value` state to object

```
state = {
    starships: [],
    value: {},
    quantity: 0,
  };
```

Now change `handleInputChange` function to accept `value` and `key`

```
 handleInputChange = (key, value) => {
    this.setState({
      value[key]: value,
    });
  };
```

Now in `Starship` component we will call `onChange` method with `url` as key and `e.target.value` as value:

```
<input
  onChange={(e) => props.onChange(url, e.target.value)}
  value={props.value[url]}
  className="input"
  type="number"
  min="0"
/>
```